# wants to capture image in by using expo camera

Tags: react-native

i'm trying to capture image from expo camera but when i alert my photo nothing shown up here is complete code of my component

```
import React from 'react';
 import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
 import { Camera, Permissions } from 'expo';
 import {
Container,

Title,
Content,
Header,
Button,
Switch,
Left,
Body,
Right,

List,ListItem,Thumbnail,Footer,FooterTab
 } from "native-base";
  import {Icon} from 'react-native-elements';

 export default class CameraEx extends React.Component {
   static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
}
  state = {
   hasCameraPermission: null,
    type: Camera.Constants.Type.back,
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
   const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
this.setState({ hasCameraPermission: status === 'granted' });
  }
  takePicture = async function() {
  if (this.camera) {
    let photo = await this.camera.takePictureAsync();
  alert(photo);

  }

   }

    render() {
const { hasCameraPermission } = this.state;
if (hasCameraPermission === null) {
  return <View />;
} else if (hasCameraPermission === false) {
  return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
} else {
  return (

    <Container style={{ flex: 1 }}>
     <Header transparent>
      <Left>
      <Button transparent onPress={() =>this.props.navigation.navigate('Home') }>
       <Icon name='arrow-back' />
      </Button>
      </Left>

    </Header>
      <Camera style={{ flex: 1 }} type={this.state.type}>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent:'space-between',
            width:"50%"
          }}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              //flex: 0.1,
              alignSelf: 'flex-end',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}
            onPress={() => {
              this.setState({
                type: this.state.type === Camera.Constants.Type.back
                  ? Camera.Constants.Type.front
                  : Camera.Constants.Type.back,
              });
            }}>
            <Text
              style={{ fontSize: 18, marginBottom: 10, color: 'white' }}>
              {' '}Flip{' '}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
             // flex: 0.1,
              alignSelf: 'flex-end',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}
            onPress={()=>this.takePicture()}
           >
            <Text
              style={{ fontSize: 18, marginBottom: 10, color: 'white' }}>
              {' '}Take Picture{' '}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Camera>
    </Container>
  );
}
   }
   }
```

here is a complete code my component please let me know how i can capture image and stored into state i'm beginner .............................................................................................................................................                                                               ....

Answer (score 1):

you cannot show a picture in alert box. you need to pass the source or base64 of image to react native Image component.

import {ImagePicker} from 'expo';

```
const options = {
    base64: true,
    allowsEditing: true
  };
  const data = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync(options);

  if (data.cancelled !== true) {
    this.setState({imageBase64: data.base64});
  }
```

and then you can use like this:

```
<Image source={`data:image/png;base64, ${this.state.imageBase64}`} />
```

Comment: how i can pass this to image component ?any example ?

Comment: @gamingumar, the author is trying to use Camera Component.
Your answer is mentionning ImagePicker, whitout mentionning the import statement, and without using the Camera component at all.
Is this relevant but incomplete or are you suggesting to use another component ?
Thx.

Comment: @HyphæneOhmen expo image picker component can be used to launch camera using "launchCameraAsync" method. author is trying to show image in a native alert box which is not possible. Camera component requires a lot of customization to make it work. ImagePicker as all builtin.

Comment: @Gamingumar 
Thx for your edited answer.
I was assuming  ImagePicker was not in Expo.